# Undefined column in a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

```
clean <- function(filename) {
   new <- na.omit(filename)
   new2 <- new[which(new$`Armazém de Dados` != "Ano",)]
   new2

}
```

I am attempting to apply a cleaning process (plus several other functions) on multiple datasets that are formatted in the same exact fashion.

The which function is coming up with an undefined column error, could anybody be of help?

EDIT: 
   [Screenshot of a part of the data post na.omit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iktlD.png)

Comment: Try `new$Armazém.de.Dados` or see the output of `names(filename)`. For more specific help add output of `dput(head(filename))` to your post.

Comment: If `filename` is a frame, this will select *columns* (not *rows*). If `filename` is a list, this should work but doesn't make total sense to me. Perhaps it will make sense if you can include (as Shree suggested) sample data and expected output.

Comment: Tried the new$Armazém.de.Dados as suggested by Shree and it returned 78 rows with 0 columns. I am a little confused because the which function works perfectly fine on its own. I will provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your comma was in the wrong place. try:

```
new[which(new$`Armazém de Dados` != "Ano"),]
```

Comment: that's what we're here for